# How to set a JSON string to Postman variable and use it in the Body?

Tags: json, variables, postman

In Postman, I want to pass a dynamic JSON string to a variable and use it in a request. This is what I have:

Pre-request:

```
var myJsonString = "{ \"type\": \"10\", \"number\": \"123456\" }";

pm.variables.set("my-json-string", myJsonString);
```

Body:

```
"body":{
     "jsonString":"{{my-json-string}}"
}
```

But this does not work. Do you know any solution for this?

If I send the request like this, it works perfect:

```
"body":{
     "jsonString":"{ \"type\": \"10\", \"number\": \"123456\" }"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried wrapping it with JSON.stringify()?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

`pm.globals.set("my-json-string", JSON.stringify(myJsonString))`

As this value is saved as a string, you will not need to use the delete double-quotes on variable within the Post body:

```
"jsonString":{{my-json-string}}
```

Comment: Does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

you need to store it using JSON.stringify

```
let response = pm.response.json(),
jsonVariable = JSON.stringify(response);
pm.environment.set("yourVariable", jsonVariable );
```

And then use it in another like:

```
"yourVariable":"{{yourVariable}}",
```